# Finder does not show file extensions on iCloud drive

Tags: icloud, finder

This is on macOS Catalina.

Normally, Finder shows in the "List View" and "Column View" file names with extensions. However, files located on certain directories in my "iCloud Drive" (notably in the directories "Downloads" and "Pages") show only the name without extension. The directories in iCloud Drive, which I created manually always show the extension on the file.

Of course I can right-click an individual file, select "Get Info", and then uncheck the "hide extension" checkbox, but I would have Finder to always show the extension. Is there a way to "unhide extension" for a whole directory?

**UPDATE**: Basically I *always* want to see the extension of the files in Finder. It would be great if there were a feature which would forbid applications to change this setting for certain directories.

Comment: Could you please add to your question whether you want to hide extensions in some directories.  Else the state of the setting "Finder > Preferences > Advanced > Show all filename extensions" might be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force Finder to show all Filename extensions by enabling the setting in Finder > Settings > Advanced:

Note: Versions prior to Ventura 13.0 will call this "Preferences" instead of "Settings" but the option is the same.

[image: Finder Settings > Advanced]